# How to use drag and drop lists in Selenium Python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, angularjs-ng-repeat, draggable, angulardraganddroplists

I'm using the [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested), it's a different form to use the traditional drag and drop, like the picture shows:

[image]

The HTML source is:

```
<div class="row dnd-list-sip top-margin-15">
  <div class="row padding-lvl-2">
    <label> Codecs: </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5" ng-repeat="(listName, list) in peer.codecs_models.lists">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div name={{listName}} class="panel-heading"> {{listName}} </div>
         <div class="panel-body">
           <ul dnd-list="list">
             <li ng-repeat="item in list"
                 dnd-draggable="item"
                 dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)"
                 dnd-effect-allowed="move"
                 dnd-selected="peer.codecs_models.selected = item"
                 ng-class="{'selected': peer.codecs_models.selected === item}">
              {{item.label}}
             </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

In .js I load the codecs_models variable like the example in link. Look:

```
peer.codecs_models = {selected: null,
                      lists: {"Disabled": [{label: "alaw"}, {label: "ulaw"} , {label: "g729"}],
                              "Enabled": []
                             }
                      }
```

But I have no idea how using Selenium Python to test this, for example put the g729 (from Disabled list) to Enabled List. Because the Disabled and Enabled words are inside a ng-repeat (it's dynamic).

Any idea? Thanks in advance.